# Scale image in Pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyglet

In Pyglet asking for `scale` of an `ImageData` object throw AttributeError:

```
img = pyglet.image.load("/tmp/satie.png")
img.scale
```

gives `AttributeError: 'ImageData' object has no attribute 'scale'`. How can I resize an image loaded with the load method in Pyglet?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to resize

```
img = pyglet.image.load("/tmp/satie.png")
w = img.width = 1280
h = img.height = 720
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=img.width,height=img.height)
```

it will resize the image size

Comment: Wouldn't it resize the window to the image size rather than resizing the image?